# Одинаковый физический размер UI элементов на разынх экранах используя Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-development, swiftui

Как поступить, если на разных айфонах, на разных экранах. Нужно одинаково перенести дизайн.

То есть, нужно чтобы на **всех экранах физические размеры элементов были всегда одинаковы** как нарисовано в Figma.

Например, если на iphone 13 mini кнопка 20 миллиметров в длину, то и на iphone 6+ и на 13 pro max кнопка так-же 20 миллиметров и все остальные элементы, отступы и так далее с теми же физическим размером что и в Figma.

То есть на всех айфонах приложение должно выглядить как на картинке ниже. **Притом мы не можем верстать отдельный UI для каждого айфона.** Верстка должна быть одна и адаптивная, но адаптив сохраняет физические размеры на разных экранах с разным разрешением и размерами экранов.

Мне не обязательно полное, детальное решение с кодом. Просто прошу направить.
Может быть даже есть какое-то решение из коробки? Или какая-то математическая модель для пересчета UI?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну в теории размеров айфонов не так много и вы можете для каждой модели подобрать нужный масштаб. Но нафига это надо на практике мне неясно.

Comment: Ну чтобы как раз на всех экранах было одинаково. То есть чтобы на других экранах, относительно, референтного дизайна верстка "не сползала" - а была идентичной.

Comment: Всё ещё неясно нафига это нужно. К тому же «идентичная вёрстка» и «одинаковый размер в миллиметрах» это разные требования

Comment: Мне тоже интересно зачем такой дизайн, на крайнем правом экране это выглядит странновато